# How to show null values in a pivot chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a pivot table/chart of revenue where some months we had no sales. I need to reflect this in the chart however instead of showing a value of 0,  [it displays the chart in a strange format:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41wbs.png)

Suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the pivot and select Pivot Table Options.

Enter a zero in the "For empty cells show" box:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly